# Stata: Having issue where large digit variable isn't being calculated correctly

Tags: variables, merge, format, stata

I'm attempting to merge two data sets in stata.  In order to construct a 1:1 match, I'm constructing a variable that multiplies the year and the identifier.  Ideally I would want it to look like 2004000000023.  However, for must of the variables the number is coming out vastly different number (e.g. year =2000, cik=1961 is yielding a year_cik of 1999999991808).  I attempted to change the format to %15.0f but that didn't work.  Any suggestions? I've copied my code below:

```
use "/Users//Desktop/Research/13D.dta", clear
gen year= year(rep_file_date)
destring company_fkey, replace
format company_fkey %15.0f
recast float company_fkey
destring year, replace
format year %15.0f
gen year_cik =.
format year_cik %15.0f
replace year_cik = company_fkey + (year * (10^9))
save "/Users//Research/13D_edited.dta", replace

use "/Users//Desktop/Research/Crosswalk.dta"
destring cik, replace
format cik %15.0f
destring fyear, replace
format fyear %15.0f
destring gvkey, replace
format gvkey %15.0f
gen year_cik = cik + (fyear * (10^9))
format year_cik %15.0f
gen year_gvkey = gvkey + (fyear * (10^8))
format year_gvkey %15.0f
save "/Users//Desktop/Research/CrossWalk_edited.dta", replace

use "/Users//Desktop/Research/Share_Retainer.dta"
destring year, replace
format year %15.0f
destring gvkey, replace
format gvkey %15.0f
gen year_gvkey = gvkey + (year * (10^8))
format year_gvkey %15.0f
save "/Users//Desktop/Research/SR_edited.dta", replace


use "/Users//Desktop/Research/13D_edited.dta"
merge 1:1 year_cik using "/Users//Desktop/Research/CrossWalk_edited.dta"
rename _merge first_merge

merge 1:1 year_gvkey using "/Users//Desktop/Research/SR_edited.dta"
rename _merge second_merge
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to construct a number with more significant digits than Stata can provide. See the results of `help data types` for more details.

But why are you converting strings to numbers? Create a string with the year, and concatenate it to gvkey to produce a string identifier.

But why are you combining year and gvkey into a single variable? I think you have misunderstood what is meant by a 1:1 match. Your merge statement could be written

```
merge 1:1 year gvkey ...
```

using two variables as the key. The 1:1 means 1 observation in your master dataset corresponds to one observation in your using dataset and has no implication for the number of variables used as a key. What is required is that the combination of year and gvkey uniquely identify observations in each dataset.

Comment: Excellent advice. Some reading of sources found by `search precision` is essential for full understanding.  It's incorrect to assume that changing the display format can have any effect changing what is stored, a misconception addressed at http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0067 Imagine for example that you choose a format with 1 decimal place; if that changed what was stored then changing the rounding to 2 decimal places would be rendered impossible, but not so.  Further, display formats are typically decimal, but Stata necessarily uses binary representations for storage.